# Google Javascript API Photo getURL returns temporary URL and unable to find photo_reference

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google Autocomplete (under Maps Javascript API) in Angular 5.

For the purpose of my website, I retrieve details of a place, which includes any available photos. For the photos, I will get the photo URL via the getURL() method.

============

**What works previously**

Previously, I am able to save the url in the database and use that same url to retrieve the photos at a later date. Example of the URLs includes:

https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipM3QnVu-6W-ZtoTry29MOzDt7vpWzPZAPZbBfqZ=w600-h500-k

https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipPQ5imb4nzfK1TxG7KAFx2vEx1SoYXeQApA6SVX=w600-h500-k

https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-l_W16EbIqzk/WS5E5R9_VbI/AAAAAAAAnD8/ajWr1IeY7solMudnxIV21vjqmxLt8CJOACLIB/w300-h250-k

============

**Situation now**

However, in recent weeks, the same getURL() method returns photos that expire. I have no problem seeing the photo when I first retrieved it. As usual, I save the url to my database. However, after a few days, I am unable to retrieve the same images. Example includes:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/js/PhotoService.GetPhoto?1sCmRaAAAAiEX-USwjAvitgPnxuaW7stCrTkQMxyydpcmlg5IrEWnSUS5D3Z2D9evQ_n41Ght-8dr3cZtjvx4oINIEpqj4Z4fvaCyqv6xF0oPC_lw88P6FUQ7SXP2vElr61Zi568IdEhBWY_7xGFNHvdQyDqxZApR3GhS-IM17Pp8oMGlMK0FrXW310tsPCw&3u2000&4u1000&5m1&2e1&key=AIzaSyAbdivx4G0igYO5yr3vTUJcQF5s8lTdXho&callback=none&token=96678

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/js/PhotoService.GetPhoto?1sCmRaAAAAkz5xG6DVQSbwHyBIQIshs2FedNARq6oG0Ea6gUxvljPdnHFJqcJniD0gkd2BZQ7-IPc6FPVlYYb7G0t8K_-8hVYizZl4HGy5V1QiE4sjdWLhyWX7MnJYEA61zoup_fbpEhDWYpcVACyQ6RKsqpyS-bQKGhQw8Tg2O8rcGJfaKI0jW3T7XKAYZg&3u2000&4u1000&5m1&2e1&key=AIzaSyAbdivx4G0igYO5yr3vTUJcQF5s8lTdXho&callback=none&token=20957

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/js/PhotoService.GetPhoto?1sCmRaAAAAfLQZlWahAqUSlQA5y7-NTeYLMDim6M1L_ht3_qNCSL4dBeX2VWVdhzuJXeqGcKN30XAv3WZHtY2QUXaoKV5fVGSUld2IdOKfV0bv32kEFUdgMlqou9Ij5YVaJ15mfoVcEhB-6hiiaiPS3349mCZMYOPyGhTrEZUg0XGOuBW1rsrLlpmaO9nvqg&3u2000&4u1000&5m1&2e1&key=AIzaSyAbdivx4G0igYO5yr3vTUJcQF5s8lTdXho&callback=none&token=38662

============

**What may be the problem**

From the makeup of the URLs, there are obvious differences. The older URLs comes with the googleusercontent as the domain name. While the newer photos end with a token. Right now, I am still able to retrieve the older photos even though i may have added them months ago. For the new photos, it expires after a few days.

I understand that there are solutions that require the use of photo_reference, however, I am unable to find a way to retrieve photo_reference via the javascript API I am using. I have tried to use Places Service method (new google.maps.places.PlacesService) but it returns the same getURL() method which retrieves the same temporary URL as above.

=======================

**Thus my question are**:

1. Does anyone know whether the change in url is intended or it may be an error from google? If it is intended, is there any way to get a permanent url that does not expire.
2. Does anyone know how to retrieve photo_reference via the google javascript API?

Many thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Google says this is intentional behavior and that the only thing users should be “caching” is the “place_id”.

See: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110711934

unfortunately, I think to retrieve the photo reference, a separate Place Details request will need to be made using the Place ID.

Answer (score 0):

I worked around this by writing a serverside function to recursively follow the redirect path and get the ultimate photo url.  Example in elixir:

```
def follow(url) when is_binary(url) do
  case HTTPoison.get(url) do
    {:ok, %HTTPoison.Response{status_code: status_code, headers: headers}} when status_code > 300 and status_code < 400 ->
      case get_location_header(headers) do
        [url] when is_binary(url) ->
          follow(url)
        _ ->
          {:error, :no_location_header}
      end

    {:ok, %HTTPoison.Response{status_code: 200}} ->
      {:ok, url}

    reason ->
      {:error, reason}
  end
end

defp get_location_header(headers) do
  for {key, value} <- headers, String.downcase(key) == "location" do
    value
  end
end
```

so now i can take the long 
`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/js/PhotoService.GetPhoto?1sCm...` url and run it through follow() which returns the googleusercontent url for the image itself.

i then pass THAT url to filestack to copy and store and serve over CDN...

bit of a crazy workaround, but it finally fixed this issue for us.

Answer (score -3):

Here is a code in which you can pass the temporary URL fetched from Google places service API get photos, and it returns a permanent URL that you store in your database for later use.

```
<?php
function get_redirect_url($url){
    $redirect_url = null; 
 
    $url_parts = @parse_url($url);
    if (!$url_parts) return false;
    if (!isset($url_parts['host'])) return false; //can't process relative URLs
    if (!isset($url_parts['path'])) $url_parts['path'] = '/';
 
    $sock = fsockopen($url_parts['host'], (isset($url_parts['port']) ? (int)$url_parts['port'] : 80), $errno, $errstr, 30);
    if (!$sock) return false;
 
    $request = "HEAD " . $url_parts['path'] . (isset($url_parts['query']) ? '?'.$url_parts['query'] : '') . " HTTP/1.1\r\n"; 
    $request .= 'Host: ' . $url_parts['host'] . "\r\n"; 
    $request .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n"; 
    fwrite($sock, $request);
    $response = '';
    while(!feof($sock)) $response .= fread($sock, 8192);
    fclose($sock);
 
    if (preg_match('/^Location: (.+?)$/m', $response, $matches)){
        if ( substr($matches[1], 0, 1) == "/" )
            return $url_parts['scheme'] . "://" . $url_parts['host'] . trim($matches[1]);
        else
            return trim($matches[1]);
 
    } else {
        return false;
    }
 
}
 
function get_all_redirects($url){
    $redirects = array();
    while ($newurl = get_redirect_url($url)){
        if (in_array($newurl, $redirects)){
            break;
        }
        $redirects[] = $newurl;
        $url = $newurl;
    }
    return $redirects;
}
 
function get_final_url($url){
    $redirects = get_all_redirects($url);
    if (count($redirects)>0){
        return array_pop($redirects);
    } else {
        return $url;
    }
}

 echo get_final_url($temporary_google_url);
?>
```

Source: http://w-shadow.com/blog/2008/07/05/how-to-get-redirect-url-in-php/